# Why do I keep getting message saying "Invalid Path"?

Tags: vb6

I currently use visual basic 6.0 and in one of forms, I connected textboxes to the database(MS Access) using a data control. It worked perfectly fine but when I opened the program in the other computers and tried to call the form that has the data control, the message saying "Invalid path...." keeps coming up.

Can anyone provide any solutions for this problem?

Comment: It's because you've provided a path to your database that is not valid from the other computers. Fix the path.

Comment: I put a database and a program in the same folder and that folder has been moved to the other computer. Could you suggest me as to how I should fix the path?

Comment: No, because I can't see your form or code that uses the path. What specific *path* is it telling you is invalid? In other words, what is the **exact, complete** error message you're seeing?

Comment: It's from the other person's problem but it's same as mine.                    'ICEL-Server\Files\PubData\ICELDataXP.mdb' is not a valid path.
Make sure the path name is spelled correctly and that you are connected to the server on which the file resides.

Comment: My program is in the USB and if I plug it into my laptop, it works but if it gets plugged to the other computers, the following message pops up.

Comment: The other users then apparently don't have access to `ICEL-Server\Files\PubData\ICELDataXP.mdb`. Open Windows Explorer from one of those machines and see if you can browse to that file.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to say the error message is similar to the one I posted. The path that can't be found is this   ----  F:\James Brennan\Quiz(Name of MS Access)  I don't know why it keeps saying it can't be found when it is the correct path

Comment: I've already told you what you need to do. Can you use Windows Explorer and browse to that *exact folder** from the other user's computers? This is basic troubleshooting, and I keep telling you exactly what you need to do, and you keep refusing to actually apply the information I'm giving you.

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't understand you but I didn't intend to refuse to apply the information you gave me. I just didn't know know what you were talking about because I am a beginner. And btw you just told me once..

Comment: I told you the first time to use Windows Explorer to browse to `ICEL-Server`, and you came back and said "the path that can't be found is really this one*. If you were applying the information, you would have figured out that what you needed to do then was browse to `F:\James Brennan` instead, but you didn't. That's *not applying* what you're being taught.

Comment: I have just started the programing so I thought giving you the real one would not confuse you that's why I said "Sorry for the confusion". I really don't understand why you have become impolite when I was trying to explain my situation clearer. And I thought this site is for helping people not teaching them. If you considered yourself as a teacher I understand why you got mad because from your perspective, I may be a student who doesn't listen to what the teacher says.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem only has three possible causes:

1. The path is not a fully qualified path. If you don't specify a full path (C:\blah\blah\file.txt or \\server\share\blah\file.txt), then it become a relational path to the current working directory. Unless your code specifies this, it is unpredictable. Solution: use a full file path or make sure your code switches the current working directory to where you need it to be.
2. The path is is not valid in any circumstance. Solution: Fix the path.
3. Users don't have access to the share/file. Solution: change security on the share/folder/file.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it!